# can not create a place on the Heroku server using $ heroku create

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

My system is windows7.

I have opened a Heroku account,
installed Git,
created a SSH key,
and now I need to create a place on Heroku server to deploy apps.

But when I type

```
$ heroku create
```

I get the following error message:

```
Creating fast-reaches-6714... done, stack is cedar
http://fast-reaches-6714.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:fast-reaches-6714.git

 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
Error:       No such file or directory -  git --version  (Errno::ENOENT)
Backtrace:   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103:in ``'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103:in `has_git?'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:108:in `git'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:156:in `create_git_remote'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb:278:in `create'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-3.2.1/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
             C:/Ruby193/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
             C:/Ruby193/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku create
Version:     heroku-gem/3.2.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

I looked at help.heroku.com but could not find answers..

What seems to be the problem(s)?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after you installed git? It might not be on your path.

Comment: thats it! thanks. If you want more points you can post it as an answer and I will green-check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like git isn't on your path, because you just installed it. Restart your terminal and then it should be on your path.